# Pause/play ALL the CSS animations of every child element

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm creating a dashboard page which is full of CSS animations. From Bootstrap stuff (animated progress bars) to custom animations.

When you click some of the elements, a near full-screen modal is triggered, which overlaps all the animations, so I want to temporarily pause them all (because of possible performance issues) by adding/removing a class to one of the top elements, and using CSS to pause all animations when that class is set.

This solution would use only a single line of js, just to toggle the class on opening the modal.

My template looks somewhat like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="modal">
        <!-- Modal code -->
    </div>
    <div class="app">
        <!-- Template -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Is it possible to add a class to `.app` which pauses every CSS animation in every child element?**

---

Note 1:

I know you can use the exact opposite of what I request: namely, have a default `.animation-play` class to one of the top elements, and prefix *every* child element with an animation with this class, and then *remove* this class to pause every animation. Just like:

```
app.animation-play .somediv .somediv .element {
    // animation code
}
app.animation-play .somediv .element {
    // animation code
}
app.animation-play .somediv .somediv .somediv .somediv .element {
    // animation code
}
```

But then I have to edit a *lot* of CSS code, and it doesn't look very nice either.

---

Note 2:

I'm also open for a JS solution, but I would *heavily* prefer a pure CSS way of achieving this.

Comment: `* { transition: none !important; } `?

Comment: Additional to what Pete mentioned, add this: `* { animation: none !important; }`

Comment: Make it `.app.animation-pause * { //code }` and it works for just `.app`, when I apply the pause class. Having tried everything, and *writing this whole post*, I completely forgot about the `*`... Thanks, you both. @Pete, please add an answer (you were first), and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a universal selector to target everything when a class of 'paused' is added to your app wrapper, however many CSS linters still warn against using these due to performance impacts.

To be honest the impact is probably minimal these days and many CSS resets for example use them.

You could use something like:

```
.app.paused * { 
    animation: none; 
}
```

**EDIT:**

Looking through the comments above it seems as though the above selector doesn't have enough precedence to overwrite the animations so '!important' has been added.

```
.app.paused * { 
    animation: none !important;
    transition: none !important; 
}
```

However this is generally not a great idea, I always try to avoid using '!important' at all costs due to the difficulty in maintaining the stylesheet with these selectors in place. If you can overwrite the animations with a greater precedence then it would be better to do so rather than using '!important'.

**EDIT 2:**

As you mentioned you were open to JS solutions, here is some JS that should clear all the animations within a given selector. I'm not sure what the performance impact of doing it this way is but I added it here just in case someone else prefers to do it only using JS:

```
let stopAnimationsWrap = document.querySelector('.app');
let stoppedAnims = [];

// Stop animations
document.querySelector('.stop').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let appAllEls = stopAnimationsWrap.querySelectorAll('*');
  let allElsAr = Array.prototype.slice.call(appAllEls);

  allElsAr.forEach((thisEl) => {
    let elClass = thisEl.classList[0];
        let cs = getComputedStyle(thisEl, null);
    let thisAnimation = cs.getPropertyValue('animation-name');

    if (thisAnimation !== 'none') {

      stoppedAnims.push([elClass, {
        'animationName': thisAnimation
      }]);

      thisEl.style.animationName = 'none';
    }
  });
});

// Start animations
document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', () => {

  stoppedAnims.forEach((thisEl) => {
    let domEl = '.' + thisEl[0];

    stopAnimationsWrap.querySelector(domEl).style.animationName = thisEl[1].animationName;
  });
});
```

---

**Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/vu6javb2/14/

Comment: Thanks, however @Pete already provided me with the solution in the comments. So I can't mark your answer as accepted (unless Pete doesn't add a post as asked, but I'll +1 you though.) Also, the impact really isn't minimal with 100+ animated progress-bars. It's a monitor-like dashboard, and users can add as many as they want/need.. In the modal is an interactive chart, which can suffer from a low framerate when there are *lots* of simultaneous animations going on in the background.

Comment: Cool no worries, just bear in mind the issues with '!important'. Say for whatever reason you did need an animation to play in the future with the modal active you would have to add more '!important' to the stylesheet to overwrite the first one, things can quickly get messy.

Comment: I'd rather handle those situations with `:not`. I currently use `.app.animation-pause *:not(.animated)`, to exclude the animate.css library for example. The thing is, I just feel a little stupid now for totally forgetting about `*`...

Comment: Ok fair enough, I added in a JS solution just to see how it might work but I guess CSS is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for adding, however it can only *stop* every animation, and it would probably hang the page for a second or two. Not recommended. I currently use just one line: `document.getElementById('app').classList.toggle('animation-pause');` and that's all the js you need :)

Comment: Yeah true but I couldn't think of another way to do it without using CSS. Guess for playing them again you could store each animation and reapply them after if it had to be done with just JS, would be ok I reckon for < 500 elements.

Answer (score -2):

```
.app {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

on hover:

```
.app:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```